# Nice server rack cabling - with higher bandwidth?

Tags: cable, rack

Is that even possible?

No, not being snippy here.

Cat 5/6 you get in a lot of lengths. Nice. Shorter one, larger one. QUIT flexible, doo.

Then you hit 10 o r 25 or in this case 100g. The DAC (Direct Attach Connections) are NOW that flexible as CAT5/6 and the length selection is QUITE low. My favourite manufacturer goes into 1m and 3m. Anything different would have to be fibre, which sort of is not optimal.

Whatever it is, I need to move my equipment into new server racks and want to clean up the cabling. The only solution I see now id to ring them on the side of the rack to get rid of the excess length.

Any standard solution?

We are talking of 6 x 100g links and 2x4x25G fanout cables. So, the problem is something that can be handled, not like a full rack of servers.

Comment: Yeah, it's totally possible. I use AOC cables for longer runs and TwinAx DAC where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally possible.

- I use AOC cables for longer runs
- I use TwinAx DAC where appropriate
- I've moved to placed switches in the middle of the rack for this purpose
- I couple these with large-fingered front/rear horizontal cable managers to take up the cabling slack
- I stagger QSFP+ ports for serviceability and to reduce density

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, basically, you leave a number of HE (2) empty and roll the surplus cable in there?